# Python null character error

Tags: python

I'm trying to install the requests module in Python, and I keep getting the following error:
`ValueError: source code string cannot contain null bytes`

I find this really weird, because the command I'm executing is:
`python -m pip install requests`

The following is the full command and response:

```
C:\Users\Ryan>python -m pip install requests
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Ryan\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\runpy.py", line 183, in _run_module_as_main
    mod_name, mod_spec, code = _get_module_details(mod_name, _Error)
  File "C:\Users\Ryan\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\runpy.py", line 142, in _get_module_details
    return _get_module_details(pkg_main_name, error)
  File "C:\Users\Ryan\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\runpy.py", line 109, in _get_module_details
    __import__(pkg_name)
ValueError: source code string cannot contain null bytes
```

I've opened `runpy.py` and searched for `\x00` and I can't find any null characters, so I don't know what more to do. Can anybody help please?

Comment: Try installing Python for all users and then try if the error persists.

Comment: check if you have pip installed properly:
https://github.com/BurntSushi/nfldb/wiki/Python-&-pip-Windows-installation